# Sharing settings of a Drive item

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking for a GAS service to determine the Sharing settings of a Drive item

My goal is to create a script that lists out, on a Google Sites page, only the items within a Drive folder that have the sharing settings set to "Can view" only (or better NOT EQUALS to "Can Edit").

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [DocsList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_docslist) service and its [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file) class are what your need. The [File.getViewers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#getViewers) retrieves the file viewers and the [File.getEditors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#getEditors) retrieves the file editors. Your task is to find viewers who are not able to edit. Also is possible to exclude the document owner, he also can edit the document.

**Update**: Unfortunately, the GAS has a very limited support of the documents [visibibility](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183965). Only the `Spreadsheet` class has the [isAnonymousView](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#isAnonymousView) method and even using it is impossible to distinguish the difference between the `Public on the web` and `Anyone with the link` options. Other classes - [DocsList.File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file) and [DocumentApp.Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_document) have no such ability.

Please open a new feature request on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) if this feature is very important for you.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe my goal description is not clear enough but i only want to list (see) files that are read only (can view only) for everyone who is able to open the file, also anonymous (shared by: anyone with who has the link, but editing prohibited). 
When i understand your answer well, this should be possible.